# Libgdx how to stop for loop until actor action has finished/completed

Tags: java, libgdx, wait

I have actors added to a group called cells, and in a for loop I add actions to a specific set of cells within the group.

I would like it so that the next iteration of the loop is not started until the cell's action has completed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {

     cell.addAction(fadeIn(1f));
     // I need to wait here until the action has completed!
}
```

Is there a blocking action I can use or something in libgdx? Or is there a specific way I should do this?

Obviously I need libgdx to keep running in the background otherwise the action will not complete at all, I really have no idea on how to do this.

I cannot use RunnableAction as that is for calling code after execution, I simply want to stop the loop iterating.

Thanks,

Comment: The below answer is correct. Just want to point out that everything in libgdx happens in a single thread, so you never want to block the thread to wait for something...that would just make your game freeze. If you blocked the thread where you commented above in your code, the action would never actually start in the first place. You need to think in terms of your events and actions having timers. In the answer below, each Action gets a delay (a countdown timer) and all the Actions will be running their countdowns simultaneously, but they will fire at different times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of blocking the loop, you could try setting a delay on each action for the calculated time it will take for the fadeIn to start running.

Something like this:

```
float delay = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {
    SequenceAction sa = Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(delay), 
                          Actions.fadeIn(1f));
    cell.addAction(sa);
    delay += 1f; //Increase the delay for the duration of each fadeIn
}
```

Didn't test this tho.